# Managing access control for individual cell content visibility in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, row, show-hide

I am making a table in Google Sheets excel. Inside this table, for example, I want all of the G column to be viewable only by certain users. When other users enter this table, they will either see it empty or not see it at all.I also tried ChatGPT but got no resuls.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

I tried a few formulas like ;

=IF(USERID()="",A1,"")

or

=IF(LEFT(USERID(),6)="surname",A1,"")

and also

"To hide the cell, right-click and choose the 'Hide row' or 'Hide column' option."
but there is no hide row options.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you using Google Sheets or Excel? They're two different things.